# Is it possible to resume a failed checkout with subclipse?

Tags: svn, subclipse, svn-checkout

I am using STS 2.9 with Subclipse plugin under Ubuntu Linux. I am trying to checkout the entire repository (with all trunks and branches) and to have it neatly appearing as a project in the workspace. What I normally do is checkout the root of the repository. The reason I need the entire repository is that I work both on branches and trunk versions, so having it all is easier for me to work.
Here is what I want to achieve

```
Workspace
  repo/
    branches/
    tags/
    trunk/
  other_repo/
    branches/
    tags/
    trunk/
  some_other_workspace_entry(ex. java project)
```

Unfortunately, we are having a repository which exceeds 5GB in size, and it is taking forever for subclipse to check it out, until finally it throws an error. So, I end up with a repository that is not completely checked out and I cannot continue checking it out. I must either delete all the checked out data and start it all over again (till it fails again), or checkout trunk and branches separately - thus having a trunk and branches entries in my workspace, which I must avoid.

The question is - is there a way to continue the unfinished checkout of the repo? Alternatively is it possible to check it out by subfolders, but to still have the desired tree structure in my workspace? If I need to manually edit via text editor some workspace files, which ones and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do an `update` and the checkout will resume. Alternatively you can do this with any command line tool.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, but I forgot to mention (now I edited) that I am working under Linux. Would it still work if I install some other svn client and attempt to checkout wit it?

Comment: Yes it would. Have you tried making an update in eclipse? This should also work if you see the partial checkout in the project explorer already.

Comment: Eclipse does not allow me to use svn commands on that repo unfortunately, Currently I am executing `svn cleanup` in the terminal but it takes a lot of time (as I said the repo is large)